# Is Dynamic Binary Instrumentation legal in UK/EU for malware analysis?

Tags: binary, instrumentation, law

I am doing a university project about performing malware analysis on binary files. The end goal would be to analyze real world executables(Microsoft Office installation file for example). If I use DBI, am I in breach of any Europeans law?

Comment: Although not a duplicate, you may find the answers you're looking for in this question: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/13439/2147

Comment: What is your goal/use case/research question for DBI?

Comment: @mrexodia give an indication whether or not that piece of software(executable) is trustworthy

Comment: What @mountainspring65 ?

Comment: @mrexodia Basically saying if it is safe to execute that file(no harmful effects on your machine). Does this make more sense?

Comment: Oh I totally missed you are the OP and had no clue what to answer. I’d say your case is fine.